# How do I replace one flavor of Linux with another while dual booting with Windows?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, boot, partitioning, linux-mint

I'm currently dual booting [Linux Mint 13](http://www.linuxmint.com/) along with Windows XP.

I want to switch to [CrunchBang](http://crunchbang.org/) after removing Linux Mint. Can anyone tell me how to do this while taking care of the master boot record? I'm still a beginner & I don't know much about how the booting process works so please keep this in mind while answering.

All the instructions I found on the internet were for removing either one of the operating systems, not for replacing one OS with another. What I thought of doing was the following:

1. Delete the partition with Linux Mint on it using GParted.
2. Format the free space to the file system of my choice
3. Install CrunchBang on the new volume.

Will this work? Will I be able to boot into Windows properly if I do this? Or should I have to do something else to fix the boot record?

Answer (score 1):

Just go through Crunchbang install and replace your old Mint partitions with new ones when you get to the point of partitioning the drive. Be careful not to delete your XP install. The install will also load its own bootloader automagically.